# Django QuerySet union throws TypeError

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to populate a Django dropdown list using a QuerySet.

**forms**

```
class PropertyForm(forms.Form):
    prop1_names = Property.objects.values_list('prop1_name', flat = True).order_by('-prop_score')[:1]
    prop2_names = Property.objects.values_list('prop2_name', flat = True).order_by('-prop_score')[:1]
    props_queryset = prop1_names | prop2_names

    properties = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = props_queryset)
```

Both 'prop1_names' and 'prop2_names' query sets are based on the same model and both columns prop1_name and prop2_name have the same data type. Error message:

```
File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1115, in _merge_sanity_check
    % self.__class__.__name__
TypeError: Merging 'QuerySet' classes must involve the same values in each case.
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: what are you trying to do? You are executing what is essentially the same query twice. Why do you need a union?

Comment: Yes, they are 2 separate columns from the same model. I want to get values from both the columns to show up as part of the single list in the dropdown.

Comment: sounds like you have a wrong database design

Comment: Both prop1_name and prop2_name are elements of a pair. The pair has a score. Yes, I can split them and have them as a single column with a pair id column connecting the two. So Django union within the same model has issues?